# SQL database : #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1 
       INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.table1_id=t2.table2_id 
   SET t1.overview=t2.val 
 WHERE t1.table1_id=(SELECT table2_id
                       FROM table2
                      WHERE table2_id=1);
```

table2 has multiple `id` values which are 1, so it gives

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Comment: I want to update overview field of table1

Answer (score 0):

You need a `DISTINCT`.

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.table1_id = t2.table2_id
SET t1.overview = t2.val
WHERE t1.table1_id = (SELECT DISTINCT table2_id FROM table2 WHERE table2_id = 1);
```

And if `table2_id` is fixed, why don't you just use 1 like:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.table1_id = t2.table2_id
SET t1.overview = t2.val
WHERE t1.table1_id = 1;
```

Comment: i want to update overview field of table1 which is come from multiple same id of table2..then what is solution...?

Comment: How about post some sample data and your expected result in your question? @VishalPethani

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed want to compare t1.table1_id against multiple values, use:

**in** instead of **=**

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.table1_id=t2.table2_id 
SET t1.overview=t2.val WHERE t1.table1_id  
IN ( SELECT xxx FROM table2 WHERE table2_id=1);
```

BTW if you are only returning **table2_id** from the inner query, you can skip the inner query altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have more than 1 record in table2 with same ID.

But if it's OK, change your `=` operator to `in` operator.

So This will be your code:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.table1_id=t2.table2_id SET t1.overview=t2.val where t1.table1_id in ( SELECT table2_id
    FROM table2 WHERE table2_id=1);
```

**Edit:**
No need to subquery, it's redundant. Check this out:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.table1_id=t2.table2_id SET t1.overview=t2.val where table2_id=1;
```